# How many cycles are there in graph shown in picture

Tags: graph-theory

I want to know how many cycles can be formed in the graph shown in the picture below. My professor told only two can be formed! I think three can be formed 1-2-3-4-5-6-1, 1-2-3-5-6-1,3-5-4-3. I am not sure, If I am correct, can someone tell me, how many cycles can be formed?[image]

Comment: 2 if you think to **independent** cycles, 3 in total

Comment: hi Jean, what are  independent cycles?

Comment: Here $C_1=4−5−3$ and $C_2=1−2−3−5−6$ are independent because they cannot be expressed one as a function of the other, whereas $C_3=1−2−3−4−5−6=C_1+C_2$ (by destruction of the common arc $3-5$ taken once in a direction and once in the other). Relationship $C_3-C_1-C_2=0$ means that the 3 cycles aren't independent.

Comment: Behind that (for finite graphs of course), there are linear algebra explanations with adjacency matrices and incidence matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very vaguely worded. However, this might be a way to think about it.

We might consider **induced subgraphs**. For graphs $G$ and $H$, $H$ is an induced subgraph of $G$ if $V(H) \subseteq V(G)$ and $(x,y) \in E(H) \iff (x,y) \in E(G)$. A graph $G$ *contains* $H$ if $G$ has an induced subgraph isomorphic to $H$.

An induced cycle $C$ is an induced subgraph of $G$ isomorphic to a cycle. If $|C| > 3$, we call $H$ a hole or chordless cycle. If $|C|=3$, then $C$ is called a triangle.

We can rephrase the question by asking: How many induced cycles are contained in the given graph, let us call it $G$, as induced subgraphs?

The set $H_1=\{1,2,3,5,6\}$ induces a cycle in $G$, since $H_1 \subset V(G)$ and $E(H_1)$ preserves all edge relations of $E(G)$.

The set $H_2=\{3,4,5\}$ induces a cycle in $G$, since $H_2 \subset V(G)$ and $E(H_2)$ preserves all edge relations of $E(G)$.

Now, consider the set $H_3=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}=V(G)$, then $H_3$ is the vertex set of a subgraph of $G$ and this subgraph is a cycle, so your thoughts are not wrong in general. However this subgraph $H_3$ is **not induced** if we drop the edge $(3,4)$. The edge $(3,4)$ is in  $E(G)$, but it is not an edge in $H_3$.